# Can I make my own secure HTTP connection to a specific server

Tags: security, http, encryption, ssl

I am thinking about writing a secure connection between a specific client and a specific server over HTTP. Of course SSL is the best and most obvious choice. But I keep thinking I could do the do the cryptography myself.

Note that this isn't about connecting any client to a specific server, but a specific client (e.g. a Java client app on my PC) to a specific server (my website hosted somewhere else). SO third-party certification doesnt seem necessary, since the server knows exactly which client to look out for and the cleint knows exactly which server to find.

If I want to upload a file from client to server. I could encrypt it manually (AES or other) and have the key hardcoded into the client app and also put in a file on the server, out of public view.

Please tell me if I'm crazy, stupid or pushing at windmills. Is my idea possible?

Comment: Use SSL, that's the easiest way and it's secure enough. If you want to go a step further you can use an X509 4096bit certificate. That will identify just you and it's insanely secure (most technologies supports X509 certs)

Comment: Yeah. I realize both SSH and SSL (even self-certified) are better, but it's more of a thought experiemnt of what is possible.

Comment: AES => symmetric. If there is only one client, and if you have a secure way to send the key from the machine where you generate it to the counterpart, then its fine. Otherwise, public key encryption is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, "No you can't."  You can write some code that you think implements a secure connection, but actually it will be insecure.  Designing and implementing a secure connection is a very skilled job; just see what a security consultant would charge you for doing that.

Since you are asking the question here, it is reasonable to assume that you are not such a person.  Since you do not have the required skills and experience, anything you produce would be insecure.

Use existing standards where all the obvious errors, and a lot of the not so obvious ones, have been avoided for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea possible, and really, if you just need to send file to specific URL, it would be easier to make a POST request with encrypted data (if URL/headers don't need to be secure for you).

Comment: How do you recommend I give both client and server the key?

Answer (score 0):

[Trying to roll your own replacement for SSL is a bad idea.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology/2210#2210)  Don't roll your own crypto.  Instead, you should use SSL.  It does what you need.

Given that you need to authenticate both the client and the server, you should use SSL with client certificates (as well as server certificates, which are standard).